# Declaratively set property of MyUserControl in MyUserControl.xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

Assuming we have such control:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set "Foo" property value declaratively in MyUserControl.xaml?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- Looking for some thing like this -->
    <Foo>Hola</Foo>

</UserControl>
```

To be more clear: How can I set in XAML a value for the property defined in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be achieved in xaml by inheritance:

You are providing an implementation for your control. So the only way to achieve a value in xaml for your control is through inheritance.

Your second UserControl will look like this:

```
<Test:MyUserControl x:Class="Test.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Test:MyUserControl.Foo>Hola</Test:MyUserControl.Foo>

</Test:MyUserControl>
```

or:

```
<Test:MyUserControl x:Class="Test.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Foo="Hola">

</Test:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: 1 - is not a XAML solution, 2-3 would not work, 4 - is not what was asked ;-)

Comment: Oops, my bad.. it cant be achieved in the same control.. Inheritance is the only way..

Answer (score 7):

I've found in the past that you can use a style to set properties on a UserControl from xaml without inheritance. Try something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Test.MyUserControl" >

    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="c:MyUserControl.Foo" Value="Hola" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for this finding! We just need to declare Foo as a Dependency Property for this to work.

Comment: +1 but still, this is only a partial solution, since Styles can't do everything that a simple property-setter syntax can do (bindings and otehr markup extensiosn). Sadly, I think it's curently the only way.

Answer (score 1):

In your control set it in the constructor

```
public MyUserControl{ this.Foo = "Hola";}
```

If you're using the control somewhere else:

```
<Window xmlns:mycontrol="Test"     ....
```

Intellisense will help you here with proper syntax of xmlns

```
<mycontrol:MyUserControl       Foo="Hola"/>
```

I'm not sure, but Foo may probably need to be a DependencyProperty.

Comment: If I declare Foo as the <UserControl /> attribute it is looking inside UserControl class for it instead of the MyUserControl.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I corrected the code just before your comment. 

In your control set Foo in constructor.

Comment: Thank you wwosik, thought I am not actually try to set it, just try to figure out the XAML posibilities :-) So was curious, if we can do this on the XAML side in the control related xaml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want is a default value for properties on your `UserControl`.  Unfortunately you can't set it in a `Style` unless it's a `DependencyProperty`.  It also can't be the target of a `Binding`.

If `Foo` were a `DependencyProperty`, you could set it in the [`PropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.aspx) when you declare your `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foo", typeof(String), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata("Hola"));
```

Otherwise you're probably better off setting the default value in code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the point was to do this in XAML

Answer (score 0):

What about a non string property. e.g.  MyCustomObject=